# What is the policy regarding using internet pictures and logos

Tags: support

On this site I have seen (also used) many clip art pictures or logos from the internet. Some are TM or Registered TM. I have also noticed that on the internet itself prople use these and brand logos all the time on social and other sites.

Since all these are used for NON COMMERCIAL purposes are we OK to use them? Is there a policy?

Comment: [Possibly connected](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/using-images-from-elsewhere-on-the-web)? I've asked something similar before after noticing the same...

Comment: @Stiv  It appears to be. But my understanding is that you can use an image for non commercial purposes like pasting on Facebook etc. Folks do that all the time. Cartoons are forwarded on Whats App daily. Videos too, So what gives?

Comment: True. I don't know the ins and outs but I did find [Alconja's answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6700/60644) to my question pretty helpful and I would say that at the very least *attribution* should be expected. I'll leave somebody else to answer fully though!

Comment: Here is from US :Fair use

Fair use is a US legal doctrine that permits limited use of copyrighted material without acquiring permission from the rights holders. It is similar to the fair dealing doctrines used in some countries outside the United States. Examples of fair use include commentary, search engines, criticism, parody, news reporting, research, and scholarship. Fair use provides for the legal use of copyrighted material in another's work but, because it is a legal principle, it may still be subject to legal debate.